# Use OUTER APPLY for SqlQuery<T> where T has IEnumerable properties

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using a string sql query because of performance issues with using Linq. Due to a lot of outer applies, and a lot of where clauses using IN. The code in this sample is reduced for clarity here. I left off the IF-ELSE statements that added (or not) a lot of code to the where clause.

Here is my business object, it has an IEnumerable as a property.

```
public class AssetBO
{
    public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
    public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AssetDivisionBO> AssetDivisionInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my string sql:

```
string SQL_Data = @"SELECT DISTINCT e.AssetId, e.SiteId, e.Name 
    FROM
        Asset.vAssetLinkBox e 

            OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT  
                ld.AssetDivisionId,
                ld.SiteId,
                ld.AssetId,
                ld.DivisionId,
                ld.IsDeleted,
                ld.Created,
                ld.LastModified,
                ld.ModifiedByEmployeeId,
                ld.CreatedByEmployeeId,
            
              FROM  Asset.AssetDivision ld
              WHERE
                    ld.IsDeleted = 0
                    AND ld.AssetId = e.AssetId
           ) AS AssetDivisionInfo   
WHERE
    e.IsDeleted = 0";
```

I then run this:

```
var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<AssetBO>(SQL_Data);

List<AssetBO> assets = query.ToList<AssetBO>();
```

I would like to populate the IEnumerable AssetDivisionInfo, from the OUTER APPLY in the string SQL. Is this possible?

I get my AssetBO object, and the AssetDivisionInfo is null. Is there a way to map it?

EDIT: I was asked to supply the original Linq, so posting it here now. I need all of those OUTER APPLIES returned with the data.

```
public static List<ModuleView.AssetBO> Asset_GetList_ByRadFilter(COG_ContextDB context, RadFilter filter, string where_clause,
                                                                                    Guid Base_ContextSiteId, Guid Base_ContextEmployeeId, HashSet<Guid> PassedAssetIdList,
                                                                                    bool Base_ContextEmployee_IsForAllDivisions,
                                                                                    int PageNumber, int PageSize, string OrderByField, bool IsDescending,
                                                                                    bool IsRestrictedByDivision, HashSet<Guid?> Employee_DivisionIdList, out int RecordCount)
{
    var interceptor = new Common.BLL.CommandInterceptorHelper();
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(interceptor);

    HashSet<Guid> IsForAll_AssetIdList = new HashSet<Guid>();

    if (IsRestrictedByDivision == true)
    {
        //db hit, so calling only if IsRestrictedByDivision == true
        IsForAll_AssetIdList = GetIsForAllDivisions_Assets(context, Base_ContextSiteId);
    }
    else
    {
        Base_ContextEmployee_IsForAllDivisions = false;
    }

    var query = from e in context.vAssetLinkBoxes
                from cbu in context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeId == e.CreatedByEmployeeId && emp.IsDeleted == false).DefaultIfEmpty()

                    //OUTER APPLY to get a list of AssetIds from AssetDivision table, that are in the employees DivisionIdList (divisions he has access to.)  DEV-3504
                let AssetIdList = (from dv in context.AssetDivisions.Where(div => div.AssetId == e.AssetId && div.IsDeleted == false && Employee_DivisionIdList.Contains(div.DivisionId)) select dv.AssetId).ToList<Guid>()

                join assetUsageInfo in
                                     (
                                         from e in context.AssetUsages
                                         from cbu in context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeId == e.CreatedByEmployeeId && emp.IsDeleted == false).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         where e.IsDeleted == false
                                         select new ModuleView.AssetUsageBO
                                         {
                                             AssetUsageId = e.AssetUsageId,
                                             SiteId = e.SiteId,
                                             AssetId = e.AssetId,
                                             AssetUsageTypeId = e.AssetUsageTypeId,
                                             ImportId = e.ImportId,
                                             IsDeleted = e.IsDeleted,
                                             Created = e.Created,
                                             LastModified = e.LastModified,
                                             ModifiedByEmployeeId = e.ModifiedByEmployeeId,
                                             CreatedByEmployeeId = e.CreatedByEmployeeId,
                                             CreatedByEmployeeName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbu.FirstName)) ? cbu.LastName + ", " + cbu.FirstName : cbu.LastName,
                                             IsDirty = false,
                                             IsNew = false,
                                         }
                                     ) on e.AssetId equals assetUsageInfo.AssetId into assetUsageInfos


                join assetExtendedFieldInfo in
                (
                    from e in context.AssetExtendedFields
                    from cbu in context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeId == e.CreatedByEmployeeId && emp.IsDeleted == false).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where e.IsDeleted == false
                    orderby e.FieldName
                    select new ModuleView.AssetExtendedFieldBO
                    {
                        AssetExtendedFieldId = e.AssetExtendedFieldId,
                        SiteId = e.SiteId,
                        AssetId = e.AssetId,
                        FieldName = e.FieldName,
                        FieldLabel = e.FieldLabel,
                        FieldValue = e.FieldValue,
                        FieldDataType = e.FieldDataType,
                        IsDeleted = e.IsDeleted,
                        Created = e.Created,
                        LastModified = e.LastModified,
                        ModifiedByEmployeeId = e.ModifiedByEmployeeId,
                        CreatedByEmployeeId = e.CreatedByEmployeeId,
                        CreatedByEmployeeName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbu.FirstName)) ? cbu.LastName + ", " + cbu.FirstName : cbu.LastName,
                        IsDirty = false,
                        IsNew = false,
                    }
                ) on e.AssetId equals assetExtendedFieldInfo.AssetId into assetExtendedFieldInfos

                join assetDivisionInfo in
                (
                    from e in context.AssetDivisions
                    from d in context.Divisions.Where(emp => emp.DivisionId == e.DivisionId && emp.IsDeleted == false)
                    from a in context.Assets.Where(emp => emp.AssetId == e.AssetId && emp.IsDeleted == false)
                    from cbu in context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeId == e.CreatedByEmployeeId && emp.IsDeleted == false).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where e.IsDeleted == false
                    select new ModuleView.AssetDivisionBO
                    {
                        AssetDivisionId = e.AssetDivisionId,
                        SiteId = e.SiteId,
                        AssetId = e.AssetId,
                        DivisionId = e.DivisionId,
                        IsDeleted = e.IsDeleted,
                        Created = e.Created,
                        LastModified = e.LastModified,
                        ModifiedByEmployeeId = e.ModifiedByEmployeeId,
                        CreatedByEmployeeId = e.CreatedByEmployeeId,
                        CreatedByEmployeeName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbu.FirstName)) ? cbu.LastName + ", " + cbu.FirstName : cbu.LastName,
                        DivisionName = d.DivisionName,
                        AssetName = a.Name,
                        IsDirty = false,
                        IsNew = false,
                    }
                ) on e.AssetId equals assetDivisionInfo.AssetId into assetDivisionInfos


                where e.SiteId == Base_ContextSiteId
                        && (IsRestrictedByDivision == false || (IsRestrictedByDivision == true && (Base_ContextEmployee_IsForAllDivisions == true || AssetIdList.Contains(e.AssetId) || IsForAll_AssetIdList.Contains(e.AssetId)))) //from outer apply
                select new ModuleView.AssetBO
                {
                    AssetId = e.AssetId,
                    SiteId = e.SiteId,
                    AssetTypeId = e.AssetTypeId,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    Description = e.Description,
                    UniqueIdentity = e.UniqueIdentity,
                    StatusId = e.StatusId,
                    CompanyId = e.CompanyId,
                    Make = e.Make,
                    Model = e.Model,
                    Year = e.Year,
                    SerialNumber = e.SerialNumber,
                    PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber,
                    Email = e.Email,
                    IsActive = e.IsActive,
                    BlockedTimeIsEnabled = e.BlockedTimeIsEnabled,
                    ImportId = e.ImportId,
                    IsForAllDivisions = e.IsForAllDivisions,
                    IsDeleted = e.IsDeleted,
                    Created = e.Created,
                    LastModified = e.LastModified,
                    ModifiedByEmployeeId = e.ModifiedByEmployeeId,
                    AssetTypeName = e.AssetTypeName,
                    StatusName = e.StatusName,
                    CompanyName = e.CompanyName,
                    ModifiedByEmployeeName = e.ModifiedByEmployeeName,
                    AssetUsageTypeId = e.AssetUsageTypeId,
                    NumCaptainsOnBoard = (e.CaptainNum == null) ? 0 : (int)e.CaptainNum,
                    ActivityTimeInMin = e.TotalDurationInMin,
                    AssetUsageInfo = assetUsageInfos,
                    CreatedByEmployeeId = e.CreatedByEmployeeId,
                    CreatedByEmployeeName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbu.FirstName)) ? cbu.LastName + ", " + cbu.FirstName : cbu.LastName,
                    AssetExtendedFieldInfo = assetExtendedFieldInfos,
                    AssetDivisionInfo = assetDivisionInfos,
                    DivisionDelimitedString = "", //must be here to avoid error when sorting. Sort is done in BA code.
                };

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(where_clause))
    {
        where_clause = DataFilterBA.GetFilterWhereClause(context, filter, "ASSET", Base_ContextEmployeeId, Base_ContextSiteId, "LINQ");
    }
    int SkipRows = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;

    if (PassedAssetIdList.Count == 0)
    {
        RecordCount = query.Where(where_clause).Select(d => d.AssetId).Distinct().Count();

        //RecordCount = query.Where(where_clause).GroupBy(test => test.AssetId)
        //                  .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).Count();

        query = query.Where(where_clause).OrderBy(OrderByField + (IsDescending ? " descending" : ""));
    }
    else
    {
        RecordCount = query.Where(x => PassedAssetIdList.Contains(x.AssetId)).Where(where_clause).Select(d => d.AssetId).Distinct().Count();
        query = query.Where(x => PassedAssetIdList.Contains(x.AssetId)).Where(where_clause).OrderBy(OrderByField + (IsDescending ? " descending" : ""));
    }


    List<ModuleView.AssetBO> items = new List<ModuleView.AssetBO>();
    if (PageSize == -1)
    {
        items = query.ToList<ModuleView.AssetBO>();
    }
    else
    {
        items = query.Skip(SkipRows).Take(PageSize).ToList<ModuleView.AssetBO>();
    }

    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Remove(interceptor);
    if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
    {
        items = items.GroupBy(test => test.AssetId)
           .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
           .ToList();

        return items;
    }
    return new List<ModuleView.AssetBO>();
}
```

Comment: `SqlQuery` can't be used for this. You have to use a LINQ-statement with `Include` if you want to populate navigation properties. Maybe you should start your question one step earlier: show the LINQ statement (+ classes and mappings) and explain how it needs improvement. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269).

Comment: The Linq query takes forever to return. It is using several outer applies, and the results need to be filtered out by Lists of GUIDs. Also using Dynamic Linq for the filtering coming from the UI. And all of this needs to be done in one call, due to the fact that our Radgrid uses paging, and I need the proper counts, sorting etc. By using a string SQL, I can still use paging, and dynamic SQL, and use IF-ELSE to add to the where clause. I will edit the post to include the original Linq query.

Comment: I should mention, that converting my Linq queries to strings, has increased the speed substantially. Going form unusable, to coming back within seconds. But for this query, I need the IEnumerable returned to the UI code. I have actually solved my issue, by running the string query, and from that, I get a HashSet<Guid> of Primarykeys. I then run a Linq query, that pulls the IEnumerables, and in the where clause, I say - where PK IN List. I was just trying to avoid having to run this massive query twice.

Comment: Yeah, that's a massive query. Hard to tell how it can be optimized. One thing is that the joins look very inefficient. You keep querying `context.Employees` with the same predicate in subqueries. Also you don't seem to use navigation properties. It should be possible to remove the explicit joins from the query and start by something like `from e in context.vAssetLinkBoxes where !e.CreatedByEmployee.IsDeleted` ... ` and have one select statement at the end in which you use things like `AssetUsageInfo = e.AssetUsages.Select(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Gert. I need CreatedByEmployeeName for each of the subqueries, and it could be a different employee, for each sub-query. Not using navigation, because I am not using entities, I am using business objects (BO), which are derived from the entity, with extended properties added to the BO. AssetBO for example. I have been down the road using entities, and too much data is returned, at times, and I ended up having to manually edit the EDMX xml, a disaster over time. I could move the AssetUsageInfo select, but I think what I have now is basically the same thing, but more readable.

Comment: My main issue is paging. Because of paging, I have to grab all data in one query, otherwise filtering and sorting could potentially screw up the record count. Where It says I am returning 25 records, but I only get 12, or whatever. The SQL this Linq produces is god awful, and takes forever to run. And because I am using dynamic Linq (the variable where_clause), the execution plan is not cached, so every call is as inefficient as the first. The string SQL is my answer, pretty sure.. just wanting to avoid the 2nd Linq query. My load time is good, even with that 2nd call.